# Where is Soundcard Directory for Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, soundcard

I'm still kind of newish to linux, and I installed panon to find that it's not working. I found a command that fixes it, but I need to run `sed -i 's/collections.Iterable/collections.abc.Iterable/g' *.py` in the directory with my soundcard, and I don't know where that is.

Comment: Where did you find it? Sound cards are pieces of hardware. They don't have directories.

Comment: https://github.com/rbn42/panon/issues/89

Comment: Presumably, there is a souncard directory as part of the downloaded panon code. You need to look for it among the dowloaded panon stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by running
`sed -i 's/collections.Iterable/collections.abc.Iterable/g' *.py`
in
`home/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/panon/contents/scripts/soundcard/pulseaudio.py`
Works fine now.